# Remove color to the right of custom hovercard in Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

When creating custom hovercards in plotly express via the `custom_data`/`hovertemplate` paradigm, the color is shown to the right of it. For example, here shows "blue" just to the right of "a=1". How can I remove the "blue"?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=["a"], y=[1], color=["blue"], hover=["a=1"]))
fig = px.bar(df, "x", "y", "color", custom_data=["hover"])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{customdata[0]}")
```

[image: chart screenshot]

(The colab notebook can be accessed [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vFCJp_g_Owoti7NVm7nniNXSQWTMFtxC?usp=sharing))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hovertemplate contains a secondary box where the name of the trace is displayed. You can [hide it completely](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate) by including the text `<extra></extra>` in the hovertemplate.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=["a"], y=[1], color=["blue"], hover=["a=1"]))
fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", color="color", custom_data=["hover"])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{customdata[0]}<extra></extra>")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use a multi-index value inside the hovertemplate? I was able to set the hover_name like this hover_name=price_change24.index.get_level_values('symbol'), but can't manage to use it like that inside the template

Comment: @Karl you can probably pass those values into customdata and then access customdata from within the hovertemplate. i would be happy to give a more involved answer if you post a question with a reproducible example. comments generally aren't the best place to ask questions because people with the same question as you aren't going to be able to find comments easily